# How to stop updating UI snapshots with Cypress e2e snapshot testing and Vue

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing, snapshot, vue-cli

I'm running **cypress e2e testing** and **ui snapshotting** with **cypress-image-snapshot** on a **vue** app. Whenever `matchImageSnapshot()` succeeds, it replaces the existing .png image with a newer one.

I run the following:

```
vue-cli-service test:e2e
```

According to **cypress-image-snapshot** (https://github.com/palmerhq/cypress-image-snapshot), base images should not update with `updateSnapshots=false`. So then tried the following:

```
vue-cli-service test:e2e --env updateSnapshots=false
```

A couple questions about this:

a) Even with updateSnapshots set false, images are still updating. Any ideas?

b) Updating an image with a newer identical image seems unnecessary. Is this the intended behavior?

Running with:

- Mac OS 10.15.1
- Cypress 3.6.1
- @vue/cli-service ^4.0.3
- cypress-image-snapshot ^3.1.1

Comment: Is your `test:e2e` task passing `--env` parameter to Cypress?

Trying running Cypress by itself, without using the task.

Comment: You can also try [another Cypress snapshot plugin](https://github.com/meinaart/cypress-plugin-snapshots)